# I'm using nuxt.js An error occurred in ie11

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, nuxt.js

i'm using nuxt.js now.
but got some error in ie11.

first I am using vuetify and nuxt.js SSR(pwa) mode.

IE11 the following error occurs.

this is my error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ks01J.png

And I use the following module.

```
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie'
import CookieParser from 'cookieparser'
```

and my some code
I am a novice developer and the code may be strange.

```
auth middleware
 export default function ({ store, redirect, error }) {
   if (!store.state.auth || store.state.error) {
     return redirect('/login')
   }
 }
```

```
login.vue [The part that uses cookies]

  methods: {
    async Login (email, password) {
      await this.$store.dispatch('obtainToken', { email: email, password: password })
        .then((response) => {
          // login success
          let cookies = new Cookies()
          let jwt = cookies.get('jwt')
          if (jwt) {
            this.$router.push(this.$route.query.redirect || '/')
          } else {
            this.login_false = true
          }
        })
     }
  }
```

```
index.vue [The part that uses cookies]

  async asyncData ({ req, store, params, context }, callback) {
    let cookies = new Cookies()
    let jwt = cookies.get('jwt')
    if (jwt) {
      let [mainData] = await Promise.all([
        axios.get('/api/profile/view', { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}` } })
      ])
      store.dispatch('setuserData', mainData.data)
      callback(null, { data: mainData.data })
    } else {
      let cookies = CookieParser.parse(req.headers.cookie)
      let jwt = cookies.jwt
      let [mainData] = await Promise.all([
        axios.get('/api/profile/view', { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}` } })
      ])
      store.dispatch('setuserData', mainData.data)
      callback(null, { data: mainData.data })
    }
  },
```

```
nuxt.config.js

  build: {
    analyze: {
      analyzerMode: 'static'
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        '$': 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery'
      })
    ],
    extractCSS: true,
    watch:['api'],
    vendor:['babel-polyfill', '@johmun/vue-tags-input'],
    extend (config, ctx) {
      // Run ESLint on save
      if (ctx.isDev && ctx.isClient && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /(node_modules)/,
          options: {
            fix: true
          }
        })
      }
      if (ctx.isServer) {
        config.externals = [
          nodeExternals({
            whitelist: [/^vuetify/]
          })
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```

what's wrong with my code? or Is this a module issue?
please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to check your code and error message.

I find that you are using **"=>"** **Arrow functions** in your code.

[image]

[image]

Arrow functions are not supported in Internet Explorer. so it is giving syntax error.

References:

(1) [Arrow functions support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions)

(2) [Browser compatibility for Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility)

You can try to use Babel to solve this issue for IE.

(3) [babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions)